# Downloaded software wont launch itself and has to be opened with existing application (Xarchiver)

Tags: linux, terminal, sudo, file-download

I tried downloading the software Blender, usually i just double click what i open and it launches easy-peasy but when i try to launch Blender i have to pick an existing application to open it with (chrome, libreoffice and calculator, you get the idea).
Xarchiver tends to be what it starts by opening itself as but i can not use the software that way.
This problem has come up with other things i try to download as well in the exact same way.

I tried to open it in terminal by doing:
cd filelocation
chmod a+x [file name]
But then what comes up is:
chmod: cannot access '[blender-3.1.2-linux-x64.tar.xz]': No such file or directory

I'm very clueless with computer and code stuff and have very little idea of what the deal is, would very much appreciate any advice on this matter.

Comment: `blender-3.1.2-linux-x64.tar.xz` is a compressed file and is not an application.  It *contains* the application (plus other stuff).  That would be my guess why you can't run it.  You need to move that file to it's own folder and decompress it there.  Then look for a single file called `blender` to launch.

Comment: You could just install your package managers version of blender, e.g. via `apt install blender` on debian/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

What you normally download may be **packages** eg *.deb *.rpm etc?

Files labelled ***.tar.xz** are compressed archives, which is why your system correctly wants to open it with Xarchiver. Do so and extract it, then navigate to the folder you extracted it to.

In that folder you will often find a file named Readme or something similar. In the case of Blender3.1.2 the file you want is called:
/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64/readme.html

Double click on it to open it in your default browser. Scroll down and you will find:

> Installation
>
> Windows: The download .zip contains a Blender folder. You may put this
> anywhere on your hard drive. To launch Blender, double-click on
> Blender.exe.
>
> Linux: Unpack the archive, then run the Blender executable.
>
> macOS: The downloaded package includes Blender.app. Optionally copy
> this to your Applications folder, and add it to the dock by dragging
> it from there to the dock.

(Its kind of amusing that you had to unpack the archive to find the file telling you to unpack the archive, but lets ignore that!)

So you are looking for the file called Blender.
(On my system it is 293.1 MB and dated Fri 01 Apr 2022 12:51:17, first file after the folders)
Double click on that and welcome to the incredibly powerful (but rather confusing for newcomers) world of Blender! Luckily there are many online tutorials eg on youtube:
[https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+3.1+beginner+tutorial+](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender%203.1%20beginner%20tutorial%20)